# jersey error handling + generics response object

Tags: java, generics, exception, jersey

I am building restapi with jersey. My sample rest GET method works fine.
In case of any exception in the restapi method my class which extends javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper catches the exception, map it to **RestapiResponse** object and send it back to the client.

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/hello/{key}")
public Orange sayHello(@PathParam("key") String key) {
   ...
}
```

My RestapiResponse class needs to be something like this:

```
class RestapiResponse {
    private int httpStatus;
    private int errorCode;
    private String message;
    private String link;
    private String description;
    private String errorStackTrace;
    private Class<T> response; <-- holds the response object of rest call

    // getters/setters are here

    // produces a new instance of class and set the response object 
    public static RestapiResponse getInstance(T response, Class<T> type) {
        this.response = response;
    }
}
```

I need a generic restapi caller something like this:

```
class RestapiCaller {
    public static RestapiResponse get(String uri, Class<T> type) {
        // jersey rest client call
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
        ...
        Response response = builder.get();

        if (response.getStatus() == 200) {
            return RestapiResponse.getInstance(response.readEntity(type), type);
        else
            return response.readEntity(RestapiResponse.class);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
RestapiResponse r = RestapiCaller.get("host:port/.../api/...", Orange.class)
if (r.getHttpStatus() == 200) {
    Orange o = r.getResponse();
}

RestapiResponse r = RestapiCaller.get("host:port/.../api/...", Car.class)
if (r.getHttpStatus() == 200) {
    Car c = r.getResponse();
}
```

I would like to ask help to implement the RestapiResponse.getInstance() and RestapiCaller.get() methods.

Comment: Which part exactly do you need help with? Is there something specific that has you stuck?